# I need to find out specific android tablet will use which layout folder(small, normal, large, xlarge) without writing code

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-device-monitor

xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp.

large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp.

normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp.

small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp.

px = dp * (dpi / 160)

i am using these folders. I am puting values to this formule. i calculate my tablets width 1300dp but it uses folder large. where can i find px and dpi values?

Comment: Those resource set qualifiers were replaced a decade ago with ones that let you control the actual dp value (`-swNNNdp`, `-wNNNdp`, `-hNNNdp`, for developer-chosen values for `NNN`). Perhaps you will be better served using those.